# Отображение прозрачной картинки

Tags: wpf, c#

Необходимо использовать прозрачную картинку в одном из окон в WPF приложении; примерный код:

```
<window>
    <image source="transparent image" />
</window>
```

В свойствах окна установил `background="transparent"`, однако все равно картинка отображается с черным фоном.

Подскажите, как правильно отобразить транспарентную картинку?

Comment: Странно - у меня png-картинка с прозрачностью отобразилась без каких-либо моих действий относительно неё ^^"

Answer (score 1):

```
<Window WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
Background="Transparent">
    <image source="transparent image" />
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день!
А какая у вас картинка?
Нужно png и сделать в фотошопе(или ещё где) ей прозрачный фон.

А вообще background="transparent" у окна делает его чёрным. Там надо какое-то свойство окна выставить, чтобы оно тоже стало прозрачным - кажется AllowsTransparency. Тогда можно сделать окно, которое фактически будет состоять только из вашей картинки и так таскаться по экрану.